# How to add a element with walker menu right after begin of the navigation tags?

Tags: menus, walker

I was trying to add a element right after begin of the navigation tags and before the ul will start. So add a element directly after opening nav tag.

I tried this, but this will add a list item after all li's. Maybe we can use it to solve my problem:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_li_to_nav', 10, 2);

function add_li_to_nav($items, $args)
{
    $items .= '<li>SEARCH</li>';
    return $items;
}
```

What my goal is, is to add a link `<a href="#" "mobile">` right after `primary-navwrapper`. Like the following markup:

```
<nav id="primary-navwrapper" class="pushy-right">

<!-- SO HERE RIGHT AFTER NAV PLACE THE FOLLOWING ANCHOR TAG -->
<a href="#" "mobile">


<ul id="listnav" class="menu">

<li id="menu-item-160" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-160">
    <a href="">Fotografie</a>
</li>

</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Sorry, you are trying to add a _class_? What you have done is add whole list item. And what does "before the ul will start" mean? Your question is not clear. Please add some more detail, particularly about the required output.

Comment: See updated version above. Sorry for the unclear question! @s_ha_dum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is unclear but [`wp_nav_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Parameters) has a couple of arguments that will allow you to add *classes* to the output. For example...

```
wp_nav_menu(
  array(
    'container_class' => 'conclass',
    'menu_class' => 'menclass'
  )
);
```

You can alter those arguments using the [`wp_nav_menu_args`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L231) filter as well.

However, I suspect that when you say "class" you are using the wrong term, and what you actually want to do is add a single *list item* to the beginning of the navigation menu. Your filter is pretty close:

```
function add_li_to_nav($items, $args) {
  remove_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_li_to_nav', 10, 2);
  $items = '<li>SEARCH</li>'.$items;
  return $items;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_li_to_nav', 10, 2);
```

That will add the "search" list item before the current item, and then remove itself so that the "search" list item will not be added in any other locations.

Update based on new information:

By far the simplest solution is going to be to pass `wp_nav_menu()` a `'container'=>false` argument and write the rest into the markup.

```
<nav id="primary-navwrapper" class="pushy-right">
  <!-- SO HERE RIGHT AFTER NAV PLACE THE FOLLOWING ANCHOR TAG -->
  <a href="#">mobile</a>><?php
  wp_nav_menu(
    array(
      'container' => false
    )
  ); ?>
</nav><?php
```

Another option is to filter `wp_nav_menu`:

```
function add_anchor_to_nav($menu) {
  remove_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_anchor_to_nav', 10, 2);
  $pat = '(<nav[^>]+?>)(.*)';
  $menu = preg_replace('|'.$pat.'|','$1<a href="#">mobile</a>$2',$menu);
  return $menu;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu', 'add_anchor_to_nav', 10, 2);

wp_nav_menu(
  array(
    'container' => 'nav'
  )
);
```

`regex` on markup is dicey but this is fairly simple. I think it will perform relatively well.